# ISCC - /D compiler-parameter seems to have no effect

Tags: parameter-passing, inno-setup

I'm trying to use the /D parameter of the Inno Setup Command Line Compiler to choose which files should be included in my setup.

The code looks like the following:

```
#define MyAppName "MyApp"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0.0"
(....)
#define PHASE

[Setup]
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
(....)

[Files]
Source: "C:\temp\myfile.txt"; DestDir: "{app}";

#if PHASE == "test"
    Source: "C:\temp\onlyInTestBuildNeeded.txt"; DestDir: "{app}";
#endif
```

I try to compile the script `ISCC /DPHASE=test "D:\foo\bar.iss"` but it seems to have no effect on my PHASE define.

So can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong? I can't find any more information at the [Inno Setup Help](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=isppcc).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You overwrite `PHASE` in the `.iss` file with the line

```
#define PHASE
```

Delete that line or check it with #ifdef in order to define it only when it is not set via command line `/D` switch:

```
#ifndef PHASE
  #define PHASE
#endif
```

Comment: The #ifndef did the trick, thank you. Thought I've to pre-define the variable I want to check. However do you now if there is a way to pass /D to the compiler within the inno setiup compiler gui? or only via cmd?

Comment: No idea, sorry. May be a new SO question helps you.

Comment: Done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148701/iscc-pass-parmeter-in-the-compiler-ide)