# ISCC passing a parameter in the Compiler IDE

Tags: ide, inno-setup

I want to know if it's possible to pass ISCC option if I compile my script within the Inno Setup Compiler IDE (optimal in Inno Script Studio).

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423317/inno-setup-ide-and-iscc-ispp-passing-define) which says I should do something like

```
#ifndef myDefine
    #define myDefine "value"
#endif
```

I've already tried that because of the answer of [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147855/iscc-d-compiler-parameter-seems-to-have-no-effect/33148208?noredirect=1#comment54105999_33148208).

What I try to achive in the IDE is:

```
ISCC /DPHASE=test "D:\foo\bar.iss"
```

So is there an option in the IDE where I can pass preprocessor parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no other way than to define some meaningful defaults in your `.iss` file.

If you do not want the value to be directly in the main `.iss` file, you can import them from other file using

```
#include "Defaults.iss"
```

Maybe conditionally:

```
#ifexist "Defaults.iss"
  #include "Defaults.iss"
#endif
```

See [Inno Setup Preprocessor: #include](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=include).

---

Note that the Inno Setup IDE does not actually launch the `iscc.exe` binary for the compilation. It has the "iscc" linked into itself. Were it launching an external process for the compilation, it would be possible to somehow inject the parameters.

Comment: Well I'll build in cmd then cause it works there. Thank you for your answer.